# How populate items to Model in order

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a question.

How do I sort the items which I add to the Model via .populate by some variable in the data?

The data I get:

```
"items": [
                {
                    "_id": "xxxx",
                    "name": "Item 1",
                    "price": 4000,
                    "order": 2,
                    "user": {
                        "_id": "xxxx",
                    }
                },
                {
                    "_id": "xxxx",
                    "name": "Item 2",
                    "price": 4000,
                    "order": 1,
                    "user": {
                        "_id": "xxxx",
                    }
                }
            ],
```

Here I want them to be sorted by the `order` variable.
So Item 1 will be second and Item 2 will be first.

The `order` variable is not required, so if item does not have `order`, it should be sorted on last position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate({
"$sort": {order: 1}
})

you can use -1 for descending order. for live test check below link
```

[mongodb sort result](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YrceXvUxhK4)